# Dsiadvantages of Add Connected reference - WCF service in vs2019

Tags: c#, wcf, asp.net-core

I have a wcf service created. It is hosted in a server. Now I have created a ASP.NET core WEB application and added a connected reference to the WCF reference. Do I need to refresh this connected reference as the WCF code changes ? If yes , then are there other ways to consume WCF in ASP.net Core ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course you need to refresh it, if

- The contract changes (the WSDL definitions)
- There are breaking changes in the api (apis removed, signatures changed etc. - which changes the contract too)
- You want to use the newly added features that come with it

#### Why?

Because adding a service references generates proxy classes.

If you only change code/logic of the WCF but contract (service interfaces and models) remain same, then its not necessary to refresh and recompile it